# How to determine the three smallest values in a variable using excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an array for instance M = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] and I want to get the top 3 smallest which are: [1, 2, 3]. How do I do this in excel VBA?

I want to get 3 smallest values for each row, i, of the array Min_NDate(i, j) in my actual code as shown below:

```
For i = 1 To Total_Rows_Help
    For j = 1 To Total_Rows_Help
        Min_NDate(i, j) = Worksheets("Help Worksheet").Cells(i, 2) - Worksheets("Help Worksheet").Cells(j, 2)
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you done some research before asking the coding monkeys to solve your problem?

Comment: I can't think of any i've never encountered something like this before. I was thinking maybe there is a function out there that already has the one I need?

Comment: So, you've never encountered it, so you figured you wouldn't bother even trying?  I think you misunderstand the purpose of this site.

Comment: It was kind of @Jeeped, to provide an answer below but seriously, that's one of a number of solutions you could have at least *tried*, that are available on the *first page* of Google Search results for ["get smallest values from vba array"](https://www.google.ca/search?q=3+smallest+values+from+vba+array&num=100).

Comment: I searched it in google and looked at forums but they gave me excel formulas of small and large rather than within the loops in VBE. If you notice the search phrase you also typed in and you check the top 5 to 10 posts, you'll see a mix or max function and mostly are small and large in formula form. I am not so good at coding so I don't even know why @Jeeped's array is 2 dimensional for a 1 dimensional array

Comment: @ashleedawg - yeah, I know; responding to crappy off-topic questions only leads to more crappy off-topic questions. I just wish the OP had left the code snippet in; I would have up-voted.

Comment: I appreciate all the help eitherway

Comment: His array is one dimensional, same as yours.  If you're referring to the two `debug.print` lines, the one with `large` is unnecessary for your question (probably included to demonstrate the `Small` & `Large` functions.)   I

Comment: @ashleedawg - I wanted to empirically demonstrate that I wasn't simply writing off the first three elements of the array.

Comment: @jeeped, good point, the code sample prompted the answer and then was deleted afterwards.  It probably should be included so that others can see what the OP had attempted.

Comment: I deleted the code because I was revising the code. I saw a mistake in my code that will confuse people more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the application's SMALL function.

```
dim m as variant, k as long
m = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
for k=1 to 3
    debug.print application.small(m, k)
    debug.print application.large(m, k)
next k
```

I have included a worksheet's LARGE functionality as I want to empirically demonstrate that I am not simply writing off the first three elements of the array (which is sorted in an ascending manner).